# Delphi Open save to XML using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 (.mdb)

Tags: xml, delphi, ado

I have a application with working in access (.mdb) my connection is made  using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and i nead to export a MasterTable and detailtables (1,2,3) to XML is it possible?
If it´s possible can i somewhere else (send by email) Open and update or insert into the database? the tables are the same only we are somewhere where it´s not possible to conect into the network where the database is.

Thank´s

Answer (score 3):

When you use `ADODataSet1.LoadFromFile('c:\test.xml')` you are actually creating a disconnected `DataSet`.

Your option is to create a temp `TADODataSet` (`MyXMLDataSet`).
`MyXMLDataSet` does not need the `Connection` object (or a Connection string).

Use `MyXMLDataSet.LoadFromFile('c:\test.xml')` and then iterate through it row by row, and post new rows to `ADOTable1` or edit existing rows.

Here is an example:

```
MyXMLDataSet := TADODataSet.Create(nil);
try
  MyXMLDataSet.LoadFromFile('c:\test.xml');

  ADOTable1.Connection.BeginTrans;
  try
    while not MyXMLDataSet.Eof do
    begin          
      if not ADOTable1.Locate('ID', MyXMLDataSet.FieldByName('ID').AsString, []) then
      begin
        // add new record 
        ADOTable1.Append;
        ADOTable1.FieldByName('ID').AsString := MyXMLDataSet.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
        // other fields...
        ADOTable1.Post;
      end
      else
      begin
        // edit record
      end;
      MyXMLDataSet.Next;
    end; // while
    ADOTable1.Connection.CommitTrans;
  except
    ADOTable1.Connection.RollbackTrans;
    raise;
  end;
finally
  MyXMLDataSet.Free;
end;
```

---

Note: the code above is not optimized/tested.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to copy your data from your Access Datasets into some ClientDataSets and have them saved as XML.
You can then distribute the XML files to used with the ClientDataSets of your application where there is no connection available. (BriefCase model).
I would strongly recommend reading about ClentDataSets (Cary Jensen's articles for example).

Comment: Is there a way to load the data into my dataset ADOTable1.LoadFromFile('c:\test.xml') this way doesn't apply data to my database

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `ADOTable` to export or import tables in XML format.
codes:
for export :

```
ADOTable1.SaveToFile('c:\test.xml',pfXML);
```

for import :

```
ADOTable1.LoadFromFile('c:\test.xml');
```

Comment: yes it´s that i knead. how can i save and load 
Masterdataset field´s and detailfields.

master.First;
 while not Mastertable.Eof do begin
Masterfield1...............
Mastertable.next;
end,
detail.First;
 while not detail.Eof do begin
detailfield........................
detail.next;
............detailfiel_1
............detailfiel_2
Masterfield2
............detailfiel_1
............detailfiel_2

Comment: Hi when i try to ADOTable1.Post; wont work is there another way?
ADOTable1.LoadFromFile('c:\test.xml')
ADOTable1.UpdateBatch(arall);
 ADOTable1.Post;

Answer (score 0):

You may use [SimpleStorage](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/simplestorage/) and roll your own  ADOTable data adapter.

The unit *Cromis.SSA.DataSet* can serve as a good starting point for that purpose.